# Ethereum ERC20 token at fixed value

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, contract-design, tokens, erc-20

I am new on this area. I am trying to create an ERC20 token with a fixed price per token such as USDT.

In other words, there is any way on the contract to issue my token to establish a constant price per token? Let's say 1 USD per token.

Thanks in advance!